# Conditional partitioning

Tags: r, tree, partitioning, rpart, party

I would like to partition a variable V2 using a variable V1. And V1 depends on a third variable V3.

In the following R code the variable V1 depends on a variable V3 such as when V3 equals 10 and V2 is 1, V1 equals 1.

**Is there an algorithm which is able to do this ?**

```
library(partykit)
set.seed(100)
V1<-sample(100);V2<-ifelse(V1>50,1,0);V3<-sample(1:10,100,replace=T);
V1[V3==10&V2==1]<-5

ctree(V2~V1+V3)
#ctree output :

      V1<=50
      ___|___  
      |     |
    V1<=5   1
   __|___
   |     |
 V3<=6   0
 ___|___  
 |      | 
0.88  0.98

my_algorithm(V2~V1|V3) 
#Expected output (optimal tree) :

 V1>50
   |
_______
|     |
1     V3<10
        |
     _______
     |     |
     0     1
```

For instance ctree is not giving an optimal classification (see above).

My question is probably unclear so feel free to edit it. Thank you.

Comment: yes not clear at all, maybe reduce your example from 100 items per vector to 10, and give us the expected output

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper The expected ouput is tree-like. Is it clearer with the "graph" ?

Comment: It is still not clear what you are looking for. If you want to split the observed data up into three groups you can use `split()`. If you want to set up a partitioning tool that can be applied to new data as well, you might consider the example `vignette("partykit", package = "partykit")`. Possibly, the `data.tree` package might also be of interest.

Comment: @AchimZeileis  Thank you for help. I would like a partitioning tool that can be applied with new data. I edited my post to add an example with ctree from partykit package. As you see the resulting tree is not optimal. This is because V1 depends on V3 but V2 does not depend (directly) on V3.

Comment: @AchimZeileis . This question is part of a more general one which is here : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330153/predictors-in-random-forest . Maybe this helps to understand better the motivations behind this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't fully understand the point of your question and hence probably don't have a complete answer. But I can make several comments:

(1) The situation you describe is a dependency between the regressors `V1` and `V3`. This is not the same as `V2` depending on an interaction between `V1` and `V3`. The tree structure you show corresponds to the latter, not the former.

(2) The tree you display is not "optimal" because - due to (1) - there are still misclassifications in the second subgroup:

```
expected_tree <- ifelse(V1 > 50, "V1 > 50",
  ifelse(V3 < 10, "V1 <= 50 & V3 < 10", "V1 <= 50 & V3 = 10"))
split(V2, expected_tree)
## $`V1 <= 50 & V3 < 10`
##  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
## [39] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
## 
## $`V1 <= 50 & V3 = 10`
##  [1] 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1
## 
## $`V1 > 50`
##  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
## [39] 1 1 1 1
```

(3) I cannot replicate your `ctree()` result. It does find an interaction between `V1` and `V3` albeit at another cutoff in `V3` - due to (2).

```
ctree(V2 ~ V1 + V3)
## Model formula:
## V2 ~ V1 + V3
## 
## Fitted party:
## [1] root
## |   [2] V1 <= 50
## |   |   [3] V3 <= 9: 0.000 (n = 46, err = 0.0)
## |   |   [4] V3 > 9: 0.667 (n = 12, err = 2.7)
## |   [5] V1 > 50: 1.000 (n = 42, err = 0.0)
## 
## Number of inner nodes:    2
## Number of terminal nodes: 3
```

Note that `ctree()` thinks this is a *regression* problem because `V2` is numeric. It would probably be more appropriate to code `V2` as `factor`. Then `ctree()` will treat it as a *classification* problem and choose slightly different test statistics, and different printed and graphical displays.

Comment: (1) this is true but I don't know how to handle this nested dependency. In my example V1 is a "true" predictor of V2 but V3 isn't and I was thinking that it can make the partitioning more meaningful (and efficient) if we can force the partitioning algorithm to make the distinction between both type of variable. But maybe ctree simply does not need to know which variables are "true" predictors and which aren't to perform well.

Comment: (2) You re right ! Thanks a lot for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood, your code indicates that you want V2 to be 1 only if both V1 >50 and V3 is equal 10?

If so, you just needed the conditional AND operator in your ifelse:

```
V2 <- ifelse(V1 > 50 & V3 == 10, 1, 0)
```

Comment: I am sorry I dont search to build the V2 vector but to partition it

Comment: @MassCorr Are you looking to split V2 into three partitions, as the tree suggests? Or are you looking to plot a tree?

Comment: I am interested in a partitioning tool not in a plotting tool